# Display latitude and longitude values on x and y axis

Tags: python, cartopy

How can I add the latitude and longitude values on the x and y axis of my graph?

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([-20, 60, -40, 45], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)

    plt.show()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw grid and labels on the axes, you need to add this command (after `ax.add_feature`):

```
ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True)
```

and the plot should look like this:

[image]

**Edit**

To enable more control on the components of the `gridliners`, set the the values [True / False] on them discretely as shown in the code below:

```
gridliner = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True)
gridliner.xlabels_top = True
gridliner.xlabels_bottom = True
gridliner.ylabels_left = True
gridliner.ylabels_right = True
gridliner.ylines = True  # you need False
gridliner.xlines = True  # you need False
```

Comment: And how can I only display the valueson the axis but not as an overlay on the map?